# SQL Server copying data and to and from from SQL Server to firebase

Tags: sql-server, firebase-realtime-database

I have image saved on SQL Server as shown in screenshot. Our server is too slow. We are planning to store the images on firebase and save reference in sql server. Is there any efficient way to do that. I have around 1500 images saved as varbinary in SQL Server. Attached screenshot is for reference.

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc1u1.png)

I am using try to use some kind of SQL Server script using C# as below.

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string firebaseStorageBucket = "your-firebase-storage-bucket"; // Replace with your Firebase Storage bucket name

        try
        {
            // Connect to SQL Server database
            string connectionString = "your-sql-server-connection-string";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();

                // Fetch file data from dbo.Media table
                string selectQuery = "SELECT Md_ID, Md_FileName, Md_FileType, Md_Extension, Md_Title, Md_Desc FROM dbo.Media";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
                SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

                // Upload each file to Firebase Storage
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    string mdId = reader["Md_ID"].ToString();
                    string fileName = reader["Md_FileName"].ToString();
                    string fileType = reader["Md_FileType"].ToString();
                    string extension = reader["Md_Extension"].ToString();
                    string title = reader["Md_Title"].ToString();
                    string description = reader["Md_Desc"].ToString();

                    byte[] fileData = /* Retrieve file data from reader */;
                    await UploadFileToFirebase(mdId, fileData, fileName, fileType, extension, title, description, firebaseStorageBucket);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("All files uploaded to Firebase Storage successfully.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    static async Task UploadFileToFirebase(string mdId, byte[] fileData, string fileName, string fileType, string extension, string title, string description, string firebaseStorageBucket)
    {
        try
        {
            // Initialize Firebase Storage
            var firebaseStorage = new FirebaseStorage(firebaseStorageBucket);

            // Upload file to Firebase Storage
            string storagePath = $"files/{mdId}/{fileName}.{extension}";
            var uploadTask = firebaseStorage.Child(storagePath).PutAsync(new MemoryStream(fileData));

            // Wait for upload to complete
            string downloadUrl = await uploadTask;

            Console.WriteLine($"File uploaded: {storagePath}, Download URL: {downloadUrl}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading file: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

But it is showing succes but not copying images on firebase.

Comment: When you use a debugger and step through it, does every step operate as you expect?

Comment: Hi Dale: I already tried while part is not executing.

Comment: Well why not? What condition it causing it not to run?

Comment: Why store them in database at all. Just have them on disk and reference the path

Comment: I hope by "image" you don't mean `image`; that data type was deprecated way back in 2005.

Comment: Thanks. The files are copied to firebase. Appreciate thought i am calling the api which is fetching those images and is taking long initial load time. Is there any other way to improve sal server performance

Answer (score -1):

Try to export images from SQL Server to a folder, this way you can visually check that they are extracted properly as a file.

Then in a second time, read them as files and push the binary sequence to firebase.

Only with code, you are not sure of what is coming out of SQL Server.